# C# How to add data to a dynamically added MSChart?

Tags: c#, winforms, addition, series, mschart

I'm currently trying to add data to my chart that I created dynamically. I've got a class (AddGraph) with following method:

```
public class AddGraph
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    Random R = new Random();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart_holder = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
    System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();

    public Panel panelAdd(TableLayoutPanel fp, string hostNameIP)
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.Name = hostNameIP;
        Name = p.Name;
        p.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
        p.Size = new Size(fp.ClientSize.Width, 100);
        p.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        //tablelayoutpanel - definition
        fp.Controls.Add(p);
        fp.Controls.SetChildIndex(p, 0);
        fp.HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        fp.HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0;
        fp.AutoScroll = false;
        fp.AutoScroll = true;

        //insert title
        chart_holder.Titles.Add(hostNameIP);
        chart_holder.Titles[0].Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;

        chart_holder.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
        chart_holder.Size = p.Size;
        chart_holder.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        chart_holder.Series.Add("Series1");
        chart_holder.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        chart_holder.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
        chart_holder.Series[0].ChartArea = chart_holder.ChartAreas[0].Name;

        chart_holder.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart_holder.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart_holder.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot;

        p.Controls.Add(chart_holder);
        fp.Invalidate();

        return p;
    }
}
```

In another class (TestForm) I'm creating the panels with the chart like following:

```
source.AddGraph a = new source.AddGraph();
var createdPanel = a.panelAdd(tableLayoutPanel1, ip);
```

How can I access now the chart inside the panel and do something like `chart_holder.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1,10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **search by the name that you gave to the control** by using this.

```
foreach (Control c in fp.Controls)
{
    if (c is Chart)
    {
        Chart ChartControl = (Chart)c;

        if (ChartControl.Name.Equals("Chart Name"))      
            //Code to modify Chart values
    }
}
```

You **MUST** use this *using*, to access the ***Chart*** **Control**:

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: or use `this.Controls.Find()`, cast it as Chart and do stuff.

Comment: @Adriani6 That would work but if he is adding the control dynamically to the TableLayoutPanel (fp), he atleast needed to do fp.Controls.Find(), but then he needs to send the control to another Method, like he did with the panelAdd.

Comment: @Alex Valente thank you sir! This was what I was searching for.

Comment: @C.User Glad to hear it helped you :)